# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer only happening sometimes

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong!?

```
   if response[:result]
      response[:credentials].each do |cred|

        AntHQ.logger.debug "==> #{cred}"
        c = app_instance.credentials.find_by(name: cred[:name])

        if c && cred[:value]
          c.value = cred[:value]
          c.expiry = cred[:expiry]
          c.save!
        end
      end
    end
```

Error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

File "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/ant_light_tasks-01095a3ea065/lib/ant_light_tasks/app/update_credentials.rb" line 16 in []
```

Line 16:

```
 c.value = cred[:value]
```

Example "response":

```
{:result=>true, :credentials=>[{:name=>"access_token", :value=>"...", :expiry=>"..."}]}
```

Comment: "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" generally means that you're trying to index an array with a symbol (i.e. you think you have a hash when you really have an array). That example response shouldn't produce that error and the `cred[:name]` in the `find_by` should trigger it before line 16 does. So what specifically is `cred` when the error happens?

Comment: What is `Integer1`?

Comment: What `AntHQ.logger.debug "==> #{cred}"` spits out?

Comment: @mudasobwa: What is AntHQ? Never heard of it, and could not even find it with Google.

Comment: @user1934428 no idea, it’s the line from the snipped provided in OP.

Comment: @sawa Integer1 is just a typo sorry.

Comment: @mudasobwa AntHQ is just the application namespace for a custom logger we use

Comment: @muistooshort cred is each element in that array specified in the response. Its worth noting when I run this manually in the console it works every time. Its just when its deployed to the server

Comment: I know what the code is saying about `cred` but what is it really when the error happens? You seem to have some logging so what's in the logs? And how would `cred[:name]` (in the `find_by`) and `cred[:value]` in the `if` work but `cred[:value]` in the assignment fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I appreciate your answers.

The real cause was because our jenkins agent wasn't deploying the code to all our instances.